# How do I merge 2 Grease Pencil vertices?

Tags: grease-pencil

I have 2 Grease Pencil strokes each consisting of 2 vertices, where both start from the same spot. (see A in image)

Is there a way I can merge these 2 strokes into one continuous stroke consisting of only 3 vertices? (see B in image)

I'm looking for something like "Remove doubles" function when editing mesh, where it takes selected points and turns them all into a single point in the middle.

There is "Join strokes" function, but it doesn't do that, and instead only makes a new stroke between the disconnected ones - even if they are in exactly the same spot.

I can achieve what I want with "Join strokes" then selecting one of the 2 vertices then CTRL+X then "Dissolve", but I'm looking for a way to do that faster. Is there any?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In edit mode, select the first stroke and select the vertex you want to join.

Shift select the second stroke and select the next vertex to join.

Use Stroke > Join (or the shortcut <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)

[image]

Note that you cannot connect vertices that are not on the edges of a stroke.

Comment: This is the "Join strokes" function that I was referring to in my question. It simply joins the two points with a line between them, instead of merging them into one point, which is what I want.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable Automerge while Drawing in Blender 2.92 ([Download Daily Build](https://builder.blender.org/download/))
[image]

Comment: Looks good, but is there a way to do this with strokes that are already made?

Comment: I'm using 2.92 and don't see an automerge button anywhere in the 2D Animation context.